# How to read particular element in an html file from another PHP file using PHP

Tags: php, html

How to read an html element by using id which is completely present in an another html file using php. I tried include but it loads all the content in that file and displayed in the browser but i just need to load only one tag.

file1.html

```
<body>
   <h3 id="title">Title</h3>
   <p> Some content about the title </>
</body>
```

file2.php

```
<?PHP

   #read h3 element using id and display

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to load the file ( file_get_contents ) and parse it using the DOM.

PHP Dom Document : http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

The class has a getElementById method : http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Answer (score 0):

file1.html

```
<body>
  <h3 id="title">Title</h3>
  <p> Some content about the title </>
</body>
```

file2.php

```
<?PHP
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTMLFile("file1.html");
  $title = $doc->getElementById("title");
  echo $title->nodeValue;
?>
```